# Flutter wrap with Semantics all widgets in a project

Tags: flutter, dart, semantics

I want to wrap all my widgets in my project with `Semantics`, but I don't want to use `Semantics` widget one by one. I'm setting keys for all widgets so that can use widget keys as semantic values.

I tried iterating all widgets in the widget tree and wrapping them with semantics but after thinking that it's not efficient.

Comment: "I want to wrap all my widgets in my project with Semantics"... Are you sure it has to be done like this? You might want to check `MergeSemantics`...

Comment: The MergeSemantics widget merges the semantics of all the widgets it wraps. I want all widgets in the widget tree to have their own semantics, and I don't want to do this manually. @AhmadF

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.